# Determining whether algebraic expression is zero

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a, b, c, d > 0$ can we determine whether $$\frac{a^{2}b^{2}}{4c^{2}d^{2}} + \frac{4ab^{2}}{cd} - 4ab$$ is greater than zero/less than zero/equal to zero?

Comment: What did you try, and why didn't it work?

Comment: Well we can take this case by case but I was wondering if there is an overall conclusion

Comment: Try finding a common denominator and combining the terms.

Comment: @wckronholm I have tried this already, I get $$\frac{ab}{4c^{2}d^{2}}(ab + 16bcd - 16c^{2}d^{2})$$ which I can consider case by case again but I was wondering if there is an overall conclusion.

Comment: Given that, if you let $c$ and $d$ be very large and $a,b$ very small, you'll get a negative number. If you pick $c,d$ very small and $a,b$ very large, you'll get a positive number. If you make the choice (e.g.)
$$
b=\frac{cd}2, a=16cd
$$
you should get $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$R= \frac{a^{2}b^{2}}{4c^{2}d^{2}} + \frac{4ab^{2}}{cd} - 4ab = \frac{a^2b^2 + 16ab^2c^2d^2-16abc^2d^2}{4c^2d^2}$$

Being both $c$ and $d$ positive, then the denominator $D = 4c^2d^2$ is also positive. Hence, we must work on the sign of the numerator $N$.

$$N = a^2b^2 + 16ab^2c^2d^2-16abc^2d^2 = ab(ab + 16bc^2d^2 - 16c^2d^2) = ab(ab + 16c^2d^2(b-1))$$

We can pose $N = abN'$ where $N' =ab + 16c^2d^2(b-1)$. Clearly, since $ab$ is positive, then the sign of $N$ depends on the sign of $N'$.

Consider the case where $b \geq 1$. Then $N' > 0$ and hence $R > 0$.

If $0 < b < 1$, then $N' > 0$ and $R>0$ if

$$ab > 16c^2d^2(1-b) \Rightarrow \frac{b}{1-b} > \frac{16c^2d^2}{a}$$